# The path of the shock

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

[image]

[image]

Here I am using the shock speed to work out the path the shock takes.

I don't understand why we cannot take the value of $u_{-}$ at $t=1/u_0$ 
i.e $u_{-}=u_0$.

and calculate the speed of the shock there ($\frac{ds}{dt}$) and hence work out the shock path $x=s(t)$.

Why do we need the value of $u_-$ in its more general form?

Answer (score 2):

I see you have skipped a lot of details in your question. But I will still try my best to answer your question. You need to tell us what kind of a non-linear PDE you are trying to solve and your ICs/BCs. From your shock speed calculation, it looks like you are solving the Burgers Equation (Inviscid).

As you say, the shock speed as soon as it forms can be calculated by using the value of $u_{-}$ and $u_{+}$ at $ t = 1/u_0$. But the shock speed will not stay constant, it will keep changing with t, depending on the value of the the immediate left and right values of $u$ i.e. $u_{-}$ and $u_{+}$. The right state $u_{+}$ will stay zero after the formation of the shock, but the left state keeps changing, so you need to account for that.

I hope that clarifies your doubt.